# How to restrict access with nginx?

Tags: django, nginx

I have nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header X-Handled-By $upstream_addr;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        break;
    }
}
```

And I want to restrict access to location /custom_admin/ to my ip, but if I add:

```
location ~/custom_admin/(.*) {
    allow my_ip;
    deny all;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header X-Handled-By $upstream_addr;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        break;
    }
}
```

not working. How to do it?

Comment: Please note that it might matter in which order `location { }` sections come in your Nginx configuration file.

Comment: Also make sure `allow` and `deny` are in correct order

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it restricting all? Allowing all? loading something other than the admin page?